# C# Trouble Calculating Delta Time

Tags: c#, time, timing, timedelta

I am trying to make a timing system in C#, and I am having trouble calculating delta time.

Here is my code:

```
private static long lastTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
private static int fps = 1;
private static int frames;

private static float deltaTime = 0.005f;

public static void Update()
{
    if(System.Environment.TickCount - lastTime >= 1000)
    {
        fps = frames;
        frames = 0;
        lastTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
    }
    frames++;

    deltaTime = System.Environment.TickCount - lastTime;

}

public static int getFPS()
{
    return fps;
}

public static float getDeltaTime()
{
    return (deltaTime / 1000.0f);
}
```

The FPS counting is working correctly, but the delta time is faster than it should be.

Comment: Can you give us any examples of why you think it isn't working ? Asking a question and only saying it seems to be faster means nothing to us.

Comment: What about simply using a timer, which i believe is built to better handle such situations?

Comment: Why not use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`? Do you need it to be really lightweight? Are you aware of `float`'s limitations and problems regarding precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of System.Environment.TickCount changes during the execution of your function which is causing deltaTime to move faster than you expect.

Try

```
private static long lastTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
private static int fps = 1;
private static int frames;

private static float deltaTime = 0.005f;

public static void Update()
{
    var currentTick = System.Environment.TickCount;
    if(currentTick  - lastTime >= 1000)
    {
        fps = frames;
        frames = 0;
        lastTime = currentTick ;
    }
    frames++;

    deltaTime = currentTick  - lastTime;

}

public static int getFPS()
{
    return fps;
}

public static float getDeltaTime()
{
    return (deltaTime / 1000.0f);
}
```